# What is the difference between /etc/apache2 and /usr/sbin/apache2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

I want to know what exactly is the difference between `/usr/sbin/apache2` and `/etc/apache2`. I have an idea that `/etc` contains all the installed packages with the necessary configuration files but `/usr/sbin/apache2` is what I'm getting stuck. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Paul I m aware of the file hierarchy, but when I change directory to /usr/sbin/ and try to use this " nano apache2 " I get a MAC coded file which is not user readable. So it is evident that it is something related to machine language, what I want to clarify is what kind of thing is the apache2 in /usr/sbin?  Directory?  File? Or executable file for the Web server  ?

Comment: Paul listen I want to know what kind of file is /usr/sbin/apache2?

Comment: To quote @PaulCrovella 's link: *"Like /bin, this directory holds commands needed to boot the system, but which are usually not executed by normal users."* (sbin)

Answer (score 2):

Usually the directories and the files in them have certain meanings:-

```
/etc - directory is for storing the configuration files.
/usr - /usr/bin - user's executable binary files
     - /usr/sbin - user's executable binary files that can only be run with root privileges.
```

Hence /usr/sbin/apache2 is the apache2 command's full path, as in where apache2 command lives and its binary. Where as all apache2 related files in /etc are its configuration files. Hope that helps.